# Memoir class command @textsubscript already defined

Tags: macros, errors, memoir

I am trying to compile a very simple document with the memoir class but I am getting a `Command \@textsubscipt already defined` for anything I try to do with this class. Something is clearly out of date or something like that but I cannot find anything.  The document that I am trying to compile is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\begin{document}
    Test
\end{document}
```

I am using TeXstudio. I have MikTex installed and I have run all updates available in MikTex.  Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you include an entire copy of your `.log` when you compile the given minimal example?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Did you already try blowing away all auxiliary files and recompiling the document?

Comment: you are probably running an old copy of memoir with a new latex, check that you have updated miktex in both admin and user modes, show the terminal or log output for that document 9check the paths to the files)